# DataSet returns empty

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, oracle11g

I get an integer value as output parameter from a Oracle Stored Procedure. On trying to get the value on code behind my dataset returns empty. I checked in on my database, procedure works well on the database. Below is my code.

```
**C#.net** 


public int GetUserID(string connectionString, ref DataSet ds)
{
  string provider = YORKU.Utility.Configuration.GetProvider(connstring);
  YORKU.ADO.Common common = new YORKU.ADO.Common(provider, connstring);
  YORKU.ADO.Parameters[] parameters = new Parameters[1];


        try
        {
            parameters[0].name = "USERID";
            parameters[0].type = DataType.intType;
            parameters[0].direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            ds = common.ExecDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GET_api.getUserId", parameters);
         }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           return -1;
        }

        return 1;
    }


**ORACLE:**

PROCEDURE getUserId(p_userid out int)
IS
  UserId_ int;
BEGIN
SELECT GetUserId_SEQ.nextval INTO UserId_ FROM DUAL;
p_userid := UserId_ MOD 2;
END getUserId;
```

Comment: Could you set a break point inside catch block and see it throws any exception?

Comment: No exception thrown. Just returns empty.

Comment: YORKU.ADO.Common is a custom library. I don't think we have enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I added size to the parameter and it worked.